# App crashes when I delete from table view and core data

Tags: swift, tableview, ios9

I have a table view set up to pull from coredata. When I delete from the table view it crashes the app with the following error message

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I have figured out the line of code this happens on. The two strings in that line of code are both nil. So for some reason when I am pulling from the fetchResultsController after I delete it is pulling an empty customer.It does delete the customer but crashes. When I start the app back up the customer is gone like it should be.

```
cell.textLabel!.text = (cust.valueForKey("firstName")! as! String) + " " + (cust.valueForKey("lastName")! as! String)
```

Here are the rest of the functions that should be relevant. Let me know if you need any more code.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cust = self.fetchResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!)
    print("Cust: \(cust)")
    let cell =
    tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath!)
    print(cust.valueForKey("firstName"))
    print(cust.valueForKey("lastName"))
    cell.textLabel!.text = (cust.valueForKey("firstName")! as! String) + " " + (cust.valueForKey("lastName")! as! String)
    return cell
}

lazy var fetchResultsController:NSFetchedResultsController =
{
    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Customer")
    print("fetchRequest\(fetchRequest)")
    let primarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastName", ascending: true)
    let secondarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstName", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [primarySortDescriptor,secondarySortDescriptor]
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: self.context,
        sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
        cacheName: nil)
    print(self.context)
    let fdrc = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: self.context,
        sectionNameKeyPath: "first",
        cacheName: nil)
    self.fetchedResultsController = fdrc
    print("fetchedResultsController:\(self.fetchedResultsController)")
    return self.fetchedResultsController

}()
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   let object:NSManagedObject = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
   context.deleteObject(object)
   try! context.save()
   tableView.reloadData()
   //self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade) 
}


func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?)
{
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object:indexPath!) as! [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Why not use `cell.textLabel!.text = cust.valueForKey("firstName") ?? "" + " " + cust.valueForKey("lastName") ?? ""`?

Comment: Can you explain what that means? And I tried but it says Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and AnyObject?'

Comment: Instead of force-unwrapping `cust.valueForKey("firstName")`, causing a crash if the value is nil, `cust.valueForKey("firstName") ?? ""` returns `cust.valueForKey("firstName")` if it isn't nil, and `""` otherwise. You need to add some parentheses.

Comment: Well I basically did the same thing by adding an if statement but the problem is that the cell should go away completely. While that does fix the error message it doesnt fix the overall issue and thats that the cell is still going to be there even with blank labels. The delete works, but the cell that I deleted stays until I refresh the table by going back.

Comment: So check out "numberOfRowsinTableView" to get the "new" and correct count of your rows.

Comment: can you try by this way : 
var firstName = ""
var lastName = ""
if let fName = cust.valueForKey("firstName") {
     firstName = fName
}
if let lName = cust.valueForKey("lastName") {
     lastName = lName
}
cell.textLabel!.text = firstName + " " + lastName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had not implemented all of the fetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods. Once I added all four methods, the delete worked perfectly. Thanks for everyones help though.